# Creating a program that generates a sorted list based off of certain parameters

Tags: python, excel, performance, computer-science

Right now I'm planning on creating a small program to create more efficiency within a location allocation system for an intern program I'm currently participating in. I have some ideas about how to approach the problem, but I wanted to get some more advice on how more experienced programmers might tackle it.

**Some more information about the problem:**

So with the intern program I am participating in, there are thousands of interns within the system which are then evaluated and sorted to go into different facilities. Each of these facilities are specialized to do different things for the company, such as one facility focusing on software programming while another one could be a machining management facility. So depending on the experiences of the intern, their major, and their location preferences, I'm trying create an automated system that can evaluate and sort these interns, therefore cutting the time it takes for HR to plan out the allocations and potential increase in intern location approval (Sometimes interns are being placed in places that don't really fit with their major or their interests). Each facility also has a specific amount of space for interns.

Just by looking at the problem, to me it's just a glorified ball and bin problem, where interns are balls with specific shapes and the bins are the facilities with a special covering that only allows specific balls to be put in them. The bins would vary in size as well.

**Sample Data:**
Interns:

```
[Todd, Computer E, 2 Years, 2nd year, Cincinnati, Boston, San Diego]

[Mary, Electrical E, 1 Years, 1st year, Grand Rapids, Cincinnati, New York]

[Jane, Material Sci, 3 Years, 3rd year, Orlando, Minneapolis, Grand Rapids]
```

Locations:

Grand Rapids: []; Looking for Computer E and Electrical E

Cincinnati: []; Looking for Mechanical E

**Specific Questions:**

1. What language to use? I would still generally consider myself a
   beginner at programming, so I don't quite understand the nuances of
   each language that I know. I have a good understanding of Python and
   Visual Basic, and since the information will most likely be compiled
   on an excel sheet, I already know how those languages interact with
   Excel.
2. How do I go about programming the "coverings" to the "bins" in
   correlation with the "specialized balls" to make it more efficient?
   When thinking about the program, I first thought about doing a brute
   force method where I would just take each intern with it's specified
   trait parameters and compare it to each bin. With more thought
   though, that method is going to be incredibly slow since there will
   be thousands of interns. Maybe I should first sort the the interns
   by a certain trait parameter first then compare them with an
   appropriate facility's conditions  or "covering"?
3. How do I approach the preference trait parameter for interns? For
   the problem, I want to put a priority on intern major
   appropriate-ness in relation to the facility. So how do I go about
   programming the priority? Maybe comparing the appropriate-ness
   first, then comparing the preference after?

Answer (score 1):

1. Stick with Python since you're already familiar.
2. & 3.  Can you provide an example of the data? It will be hard to give a specific answer without it.

From the data, we can design the coverings (how specific do we want our match to be). After, we can design the assignment algorithm.

Very generally: It seems you prioritize major, we could sort the interns by that. Some majors shouldn't go to certain facilities (e.g. don't send the chemical engineer to HR) so we can limit how many facilities an intern is eligible for. After sorting by major we can further refine our pre-assignment sort by doing a similar sort with the intern's interests.

Comment: So lets say I have a sample of 3 interns and 2 facilities. An intern will be programmed as an object, as such, it's attributes will probably be set in a list like [Name, Major, Experience in the company, School Year, Location Preferences]. Facilities will be a list to contain the object of interns. Each facility should have some conditions to limit who can be assigned to that facility. Let's say that the condition should be the major and the preference. My problem with trying to sort out the interns with a preference parameter is trying to quantify preference. So how do I sort the 3 interns?